# Reset an @iolfree.ie e-mail password

Tags: email, passwords

The main e-mail address I use to sign up to websites is something `@iolfree.ie`. I've not signed into that site in ages. Instead, I have Gmail set up to sign in over POP3 and retrieve messages. I want to switch from using Gmail on that account to using a desktop mail client. The first thing I have to do, then, is reset the password, since I've forgotten it. (Gmail obviously has the password stored somewhere, but I'm pretty confident it won't let me see it.)

The problem is that IOL has been bought and sold a few times. There have been mergers and deals. And now no one seems to know who is actually responsible for that domain. According to a whois lookup, it's owned by Esat Telecommunications. I think they've been bought out by BT Ireland (who own the related `iol.ie` domain name), who then sold some of it off to Vodafone. And you can't sign into the Vodafone technical support forums unless you have a Vodafone mobile phone, which I don't.

Basically, it's a mess. I phoned BT Customer support and worked my way through the menus till I was told to ring Vodafone, and given a phone number. I rang that number and worked my way through the menus till the phone started ringing ... and ringing ... and ringing. I gave up and phoned a different number advertised on the Vodafone website, worked my way through the menus and finally got to speak to a human being, who told me Vodafone aren't responsible for those e-mail addresses.

Surely there's some way to do this. The service is still live. E-mails sent to that address still get through to me. Someone must be running it, unless it's being operated by ghosts.

Comment: I managed to remember my password. I'd still like to reset it.